# Getting values from dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a .html which is a form with some selects, inputs.. in JQuery Mobile. The form is generated dynamically because at first I ask to a web service for the data needed, so once I have the information from the server I start to 'paint' the html with Javascript (For example: if (string) document.write  +  ...) It is working fine but now I have to get that data and send it back to the server.

My doubt is that I don't know if there is a 'best' way to do it. I have thought in generate and store the ID's from each parameter and the type in a array at same time I paint them and after ask them about the values.

It could be done that way? I have read about generate an array when clicking 'submit' and then generate the parameters but I can't see it clearly because I don't send that data literally, I have to process it first generating and XML and that stuff.

I know it could sound like a mess =(, sorry for my english and thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is an example of my JS code

[image]

So it could generate 1, 2, 3.. infinites Strings interfaces (well, not that much) so if I want a function to recollect the values of the 'inputs', 'selects'... generated, how could I do it?

Comment: Can you post a sample? a JSFiddle would be best..

Comment: I have tried adding some information to my question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Tutorial to form post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/My_first_HTML_form)

Basically you specify the form to post to a specific URL, and then you just need your server to handle the response. The link above should be helpful in figuring it out! Alternatively, you can use AJAX to send data as well. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Well, the problem is that I have to process the data before send it to the server.

Comment: If you are doing preprocessing, just use a REST endpoint and hit it with an AJAX request. Then you can easily just wrap everything you want in a JSON object, and ship it up.

Comment: I think my problem is more simple than that. For example, a good point will be that if I can put an 'action="javascripFunction(array)"' and I received and array with the variables or something like that.